# Keras custom loss function with samples from complete input dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to devise a custom loss function for Variational auto-encoder in Keras with two parts: `reconstruction loss` and `divergence loss`. However, instead of using the gaussian distribution for divergence loss, I want to sample randomly from the input and then perform the divergence loss based on the sampled inputs. However, I do not know how to sample inputs which are from the complete datastet and then perform a loss with respect to it. The encoder model is:

```
x_input = Input((input_size,))
enc1 = Dense(encoder_size[0], activation='relu')(x_input)
drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc1)
enc2 = Dense(encoder_size[1], activation='relu')(drop)
drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc2)
mu = Dense(latent_dim, activation='linear', name='encoder_mean')(drop)
encoder = Model(x_input,mu)
```

The structure of loss should be:

```
# the input is the placeholder for the complete input
def loss(x, y, input):
    reconstruction_loss = mean_squared_error(x, y)
    sample_num = 100
    sample_input = sample_from_input(input, sample_num)
    sample_encoded = encoder.predict(sample_input) <-- this would not work with placeholder
    sample_prior = gaussian(mean=0, std=1)
    # perform KL divergence between sample_encoded and sample_prior
```

I have not found anything similar given. It would be great if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your code. First, when you create your custom loss function, it expects only two (equivalent) parameters of `y_true` and `y_pred`. So you will not be able to pass explicitly the parameter of `input` in your case. If you wish to pass additional parameters, you have to use the concept of nested function.

Next thing is inside `predict` function you will not be able to pass TensorFlow placeholders. You will have to pass Numpy array equivalents in it. So I would recommend you to rewrite your `sample_from_input` which samples from a set of file path inputs, reads it and sends a Numpy array of file data. Also, in the parameter of `input_data`, pass it the file paths where your data is present.

I have enclosed only the relevant parts of code.

```
def custom_loss(input_data):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    reconstruction_loss = mean_squared_error(x, y)
    sample_num = 100
    sample_input = sample_from_input(input_data)
    # sample_input is a Numpy array
    sample_encoded = encoder.predict(sample_input) 
    sample_prior = gaussian(mean=0, std=1)
    # perform KL divergence between sample_encoded and sample_prior
    divergence_loss = # Your logic returning a numeric value
    return reconstruction_loss + divergence_loss
  return loss

encoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss('<<input_data_path>>'))
```